# JDBC-ODBC error with MS Access

Tags: java

I have a problem with JDBC-ODBC connection.

1. There are 60 PCs with Win - 7 64bit, MS Office 2010 32bit, JRE java version 1.7.0_55 and higher and all of them 64bit.
2. I have developed some program and installed on these 60 machines.
3. Pgogram developed in Java and No Web-based, just GUI program.
4. The program works fine on all these machines excepting 2 PCs.

When start the program and program tries to connect to MS Access 2010 32bit Database via JDBC-ODBC connection bellow screen shot error appears.

[image: http://www.freeuploadimages.org/images/ausvbpdk1oovzjubk2h.jpg]
http://www.freeuploadimages.org/images/ausvbpdk1oovzjubk2h.jpg

After that I have re-installed one of the PCs with the same Win7, office 32 bit and program works fine. I have done with second one too but program on that PC still doesn't want to work and above error appears. 
Please see below how i start jar file for connection to 32Bit MS Access:

start "CallListGUI startup" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -D32 -jar "C:\SafetyInspectionRegister\SafetyInspectonRegister.jar" -Dfile.encoding=cp1251 -reuseview %*

Can someone help me with this issue please?

Comment: What JDBC driver do you use? If using the old JDBC-ODBC Bridge from Sun, you should know that product was never intended for use in production. It was meant merely for study, when learning JDBC. Oracle has [terminated the JDBC-ODBC Bridge project](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html).

Answer (score 0):

I use usual ODBC-JDBC Bridge:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Properties connInfo = new Properties();
connInfo.put("", "");
connInfo.put("","");
connInfo.put("charSet", "cp1251");
Connection _connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:SAFETYDATABASE", connInfo);
_statement = _connection.createStatement();
```

I use JRE 1.7 and not 8 version, so as i explained 60 PCs work fine exepting 1 PC right now.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.